# Did Krishna show evidence of being God in the Mahabharata after the war was over?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, avatars

Not counting events in Harivamsa.

He saved Parikshit and assuming the story is not interpolated he save Bhima from Dhritarashtra's embrace by substituting an iron statue.

From then on until his death in the 16th parva (Mausala Parva), did he show evidence of his avatara nature?.

Comment: Considering intent, this should be a duplicate of [Why didn't Lord Krishna in His time just tell everyone that He's God so everyone could see God?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16815/why-didnt-lord-krishna-in-his-time-just-tell-everyone-that-hes-god-so-everyone)

Comment: Related [What events in mahabharata can be explained only if Krishna was God?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24739/5212)

Answer (score 2):

If by "God", you mean depicting "supernatural" behaviour, then Krishna showed his universal form mainly twice. Both of them were before the Mahabharata war.
Once during the final peace negotiation (Udyoga Parva) and then during the discourse of Bhagavad Gita (Chapter 11). Refer:
[How is 'Vishwa Virat Swaroop' of Lord Krishna described in Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7654/1049)

In fact, both the times only few could bear the light of his form and recognise him as part of supreme.

**After that he never showed such form. Regardless of that, he was never behind proving himself to be a "God". It were others who identified that.**

Comment: After Karna came into the war, He made everybody on the Kaurava side forget about using Karna's Vasavi Shakti on Arjuna until it was wasted on Ghatotkacha.  I am talking about such examples.

Comment: @SK, It was incidentally they forgot about Vasavi shakti. Out of love, people would have associated that "forgetfullness" with Krishna. As per scriptures, it was all good luck. Read [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24415/1049). Krishna always played cautious, not to expose Arjuna in presence of Karna during the battlefield. Similarly, Jayadratha's death was also somehow related to Krishna's illusion, However in reality it would be some special day or some cloudy day. Krishna didn't participate in war actively or passively. He just did his duty of being a "*Saarathy*" (Guide).

Comment: If you say Krishna's "Godly acts" are only peoples' interpretations out of their love, you won't hear objections from me @iammind

Comment: @SK, IMHO most of the deeds of Krishna, whether good or bad, just or unjust, fair or unfair -- usually are justified by the devotees out of love. The main reason for them to do such is that, Krishna was "God". Krishna's supremeness gets covered up, if we try to justify his acts. Krishna had his equal share of all qualities like anyone of us. However he was also realised that whatever he is acting, he is Not the doer. Personally for me, this surrendering of "doership" over any of his acts -- makes him worship-able.

Answer (score 1):

Krishna also showed his Vishwaroopa to Sage Uttanka after the Kurukshetra war.

> *Vaisampayana continued, 'Gratified with him, the holy one then **showed Utanka that eternal Vaishnava form which Dhananjaya of great intelligence had seen.** Utanka beheld the high-souled Vasudeva's
> universal form, endued with mighty arms. The effulgence of that form
> was like that of a blazing fire of a thousand suns. It stood before
> him filling all space. It had faces on every side. Beholding that high
> and wonderful **Vaishnava form of Vishnu**, in act,* *seeing the Supreme
> Lord (in that guise), the Brahmana Utanka became filled with wonder.'*

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m14/m14055.htm

Anugita Parva, Section LV

Comment: You should cite some sources :)

Comment: Ok. I have posted sources now.